# External HDD keeps connecting and reconnecting

Tags: usb, laptop, external-hard-drive, connection, windows-11

I have an HP 15t-dw300 with Windows 11 installed on it and a Silicon Power A85 2TB external hard drive. When I connect the hard drive to my laptop it keeps connecting and disconnecting. I have tried updating the BIOS, checking for driver updates, and using Ubuntu Live to check if anything is wrong with Windows, but none of these solved the problem.

By the way my laptop's USB ports work just fine with any other USB device that I have used. I have only encountered this issue with my hard drive. The hard drive also works fine with my other laptop.
When the HDD disconnects, it says "drive deleted" in device manager's logs, and refers to the problem as 0x2d.

The frequency at which it connects and disconnects is under 5 seconds.
I have also tried measuring the power that the port can provide by measuring how much current it can supply to my phone when charging; it was about 450 milli amp. But it could be that the app I used to measure that measures the current entering the battery which could be at a lower voltage and therefore when converted to 5 volts it could have been supplying less current. I also remember the hdd working fine a few months back so if I remember that correctly I think it's unlikely that something has gone wrong with the hardware and therefore in my opinion its more likely a bios issue that hasn't been fixed yet. But then again I could be mistaken and it could have always been like this.

Comment: At what frequency is it connecting and disconnecting? If it's seconds, your laptop may not be able to provide enough power towards the USB HDD. Oldfashioned spinning HDDs need to draw a lot of power to spin up to operating speed. If so, you can mitigate this with an external, powered USB hub (that comes with its own power supply).

Comment: "Power supplied through USB" in the specification of A85 I found is probably the key. One of your computers is unable to provide enough power.

Comment: If, as @KamilMaciorowski states, it's a USB power issue, you might try using a *powered* USB hub 'twixr the PC and HDD.

Comment: I posted both of these things. If there is consensus, shall I turn my comment into an answer?

Comment: @MiG I posted a comment, not an answer, because I treat what we said as a *hypothesis*. I tend to post well researched answers, even if they include hypotheses. In this case I cannot research as thoroughly as I would like. Still the hypothesis seems very probable and I will upvote an answer that states it. It may be your answer.

Comment: You can imagine it feels a bit strange when two further comments say exactly the same thing, while seemingly ignoring the initial comment. Anyway, the topic starter hasn't provided any additional elaboration yet, so yeah, right now all we can do is guess...

Comment: @MiG I was typing my comment when you posted yours. I decided not to delete (yet), because "Power supplied through USB" is really in the specification ([here](https://www.silicon-power.com/web/product-Armor_A85)) and this supports all our comments. I mean if we didn't know whether the HDD had its own PSU or not, then our comments would be more "guessy". Thanks to my comment we do know the HDD has no PSU. I will delete my comments after a decent answer appears.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. The frequency is under 5 seconds. I have also updated my question and provided a bit more information and also speculation. As for trying a powered USB hub, I don't currently have one so I will try that solution when I have one.

Comment: The HDD working fine on another laptop means insufficient USB power is the most likely case. Powered USB hubs aren't terribly expensive fortunately. If you acquire one, let us know how it went :)

Comment: I have tested it with another Laptop and it works just fine.

Comment: That's what I'm acknowledging :) HDD works fine on another laptop -> USB power on first laptop probably insufficient -> buy powered USB hub

Comment: I think there was another comment that suggested i try it woth another pc. And it was deleted. I dunno maybe i was just mistaken :)

Comment: I wrote that just before you made your edits and comments which made that irrelevant, so I deleted it :)